# pot histograms and had error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r, histogram

update:

Turned out it's caused by different classes of variables.

Many thanks to @r2evans, who solved this issue by converting interger64 to numeric when reading the data. His method is effective, but what's worth studying further is his problem-solving logic.

I deleted the data for confidentiality reasons.

### Below is the previous question

I plotted histograms of all numeric clomuns in my data table.

```
head(dt) %>%
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>% na.omit() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
  geom_histogram()
```

I chose head() as the data table is too large.

then I had this error:

> Error in if (length(unique(intervals)) > 1 & any(diff(scale(intervals)) <  :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Then I let

```
eg <- head(dt)
write.csv2(head(dt), "eg.csv")
```

and saved eg [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deborah-Jia/Complete_Analysis_da2/main/eg.csv) on github.

then

```
eg <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deborah-Jia/Complete_Analysis_da2/main/eg.csv")

eg %>%
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>% na.omit() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
  geom_histogram()
```

I got those right histograms!

What happened when I saved the data and read it again? Or is there a way to fix dt?

PS: dt was also created from saving csv and reading from fread.
when I use

```
eg <- head(dt, 10000)
```

and save it on [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deborah-Jia/Complete_Analysis_da2/main/eg1.csv), read again. same error happened.

Is it because my dt is too long (3 million rows) and had some wrong rows?

Comment: Your second (working) code block includes `na.omit()` whereas your first (failing) code does not. A true comparison would normalize the code between calls. (Without knowing the data pre-`write.csv2`, I don't know that we can know for sure what the issue is.)

Comment: thank you! I realized I had a typo. tbh both chunks have `na.omit`.

Comment: Since it works with the githubusercontent data for both you and us, perhaps it would be beneficial to give us the pre-`write.csv2` data. Can you paste the output from `dput(head(dt))`?

Comment: thank you! a larger part of dt is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deborah-Jia/Complete_Analysis_da2/main/eg1.csv
using the same plotting code, can you take a look at the bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <strike>problem</strike> ***symptom*** is that two of your fields <strike>are</strike> ***appear*** invariant. After downloading the full data `dt`:

```r
dt <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deborah-Jia/Complete_Analysis_da2/main/eg1.csv")
dt %>%
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  summarize(v = var(value))
# Warning: attributes are not identical across measure variables;
# they will be dropped
# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#   key                         v
#   <chr>                   <dbl>
# 1 area_size_high        1.00e18
# 2 area_size_low         3.64e10
# 3 lot_size_high         8.76e17
# 4 lot_size_low          5.60e 5
# 5 price_huf_high        0.         ### problem!
# 6 price_huf_low         0.     
# 7 total_room_count_high 3.23e17
# 8 total_room_count_low  1.46e 0
# 9 V1                    8.33e 6
```

(Many plots tend to implode when the data is invariant.)

This is confusing, though, because `head(dt)` definitely shows different values (right side):

```
          V1         ds                            search_id property_type property_subtype price_huf_low price_huf_high
       <int>     <IDat>                               <char>        <char>           <char>         <i64>          <i64>
    1:     1 2021-02-15 ad2be212-0c25-4e3a-aabf-be089053beba         house             <NA>      45000000       69000000
    2:     2 2021-02-15 ab72ba19-d00f-49e2-8d0d-c6836f030758     apartment             <NA>             0       48000000
    3:     3 2021-02-06 24bbb050-2ecb-4078-a8dc-65e968f72f43     apartment             <NA>     150000000      200000000
    4:     4 2021-02-06 f7d87e6e-0f24-4d9e-ae82-2a448d6290bf     apartment             <NA>       2000000       29000000
    5:     5 2021-02-14 71ea3cc4-5326-4bbe-a2ff-20dbae0d9aa8     apartment             <NA>     200000000      400000000
```

(truncated).

However, the key to see there is the `i64`, noting that these are 64-bit integers.

```r
sapply(dt, function(z) class(z)[1])
#                    V1                    ds             search_id         property_type      property_subtype 
#             "integer"               "IDate"           "character"           "character"           "character" 
#         price_huf_low        price_huf_high         area_size_low        area_size_high          lot_size_low 
#           "integer64"           "integer64"             "integer"             "integer"             "integer" 
#         lot_size_high  total_room_count_low total_room_count_high              district 
#             "integer"             "integer"             "integer"           "character"
```

You can fix this in one of two ways:

1. Fix it when you read it in (recommended):

   ```r
   dt <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deborah-Jia/Complete_Analysis_da2/main/eg1.csv",
               integer64 = "numeric")
   ```
2. Fix it with data in your environment:

   ```r
   ### data.table (since you used `fread`)
   dt[, c("price_huf_low", "price_huf_high") := lapply(.SD, as.numeric),
      .SDcols = c("price_huf_low", "price_huf_high")]

   ### or dplyr
   dt %>%
     mutate(across(starts_with("price"), as.numeric)) %>% # ... rest of your pipe
   ### if more than 'price_*' columns:
   dt %>%
     mutate(across(where(~ inherits(., "integer64")), as.numeric)) %>% # ...
   ```

Either way, once those two columns are converted to `numeric`, they can be plotted with your original code:

```r
dt %>%
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>% na.omit() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
  geom_histogram()
```

[image: proper multi-variable histogram]

Comment: thank you dear r2evans! I never thought it would be a class issue! I tried your method and it works perfectly!

There are some extreme values in prices, and I wanna drop them after plotting the histograms and using describe/summary. Turned out with this int64 prob, I even couldn't use `Hmisc::describe()`! 

your solution saved my project. I don't know how to express my gratitude more.